# MCU based I2C master receiver mode includes transmitter mode or not?

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, serial-bus, peripheral

If I am programming an MCU I2C peripheral as a master of I2C bus that will be receiving data from other slaves on the bus. So I will set its direction as 'I2C_Receiver.'

But since an I2C slave will only send its data to the master after the master sends it the command to do so, does it mean that to send the command to the slave I will have to configure the master direction as 'I2C_Transmitter' and send the command first to the slave? Then I change its direction to 'I2C_Receiver' to be able to receive the data from the slave?

Or do I only configure the master in 'I2C_Receiver' direction and that includes the transmitter by default?

The MCU will be [RM57L843](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/rm57l843.pdf).

Comment: What do you mean by "I2C_Receiver" and "I2C_Transmitter" directions? Any transfer on the I²C is bidirectional, beginning with: the master addresses the slave which will respond with the acknowledge bit, given everything is correct.

Comment: If Master direction is 'I2C_Receiver' it means Slave will send the data and Master will receive it. But what I don't understand is that to send the Address of the Slave should I be making the Master direction 'I2C_Transmitter' so that it can send the 7-bit Slave address? And then  I change its direction to 'I2C_Receiver' so that now the Master can start receiving the data bytes which are being sent by Slave. Or should I configure direction of Master as 'I2C_Receiver' and expect that its I2C driver and peripheral will first send Slave address automatically before receiving data from Slave?

Comment: The concepts of "I2C_Receiver" and "I2C_Transmitter" are flawed. As @thebusybee already said, I2C communication is always bi-directional. A slave can never initiate communication, the master always speaks first (by transmitting the slave address and R/W bit).

Comment: Where and how do you want to set the direction? I don't know of any implementation, software or hardware, which needs to have a direction set. What you have to set is the mode, master or slave.